# ClusterClassify and FeatureTypes

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that I want to classify in clusters. All values are numbers.

For some variables, the values can represent a real measure (a distance, a weight...) but for some other variables, the values are just representing a category (a postal code...etc).

With keeping FeatureTypes->Automatic, Mathematica decides to consider some variables as "numerical" and some others as "nominal".
[image]

What is the good practice? Should I specify

-"Numerical" for variables representing real mesures,

-and "Nominal" for variables representing categories?

Thanks for your help.